# Vuetify: How to create a triangle badge?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I understand if I use v-badge, I get a circle badge but I want a triangle badge instead like below.

[image]

Could anyone give an advice of how to make it?

Thank you.

Comment: Try [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path), also [clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) is a great tool to create an arbitrary clip path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `v-badge`'s `badge` slot to insert a `div` with `1`, and style that `div`

1. In the template, apply a class to `v-badge` (named `"triangle"`), and insert a `div` in the `badge` slot to contain the number along with a class (named `"my-badge"`):

   ```html
   <v-badge class="triangle">
     <template v-slot:badge>
       <div class="my-badge">1</div>
     </template>
   </v-badge>
   ```
2. Add CSS styles for the `.triangle .v-badge__badge` and `.my-badge`:

   ```css
   .triangle .v-badge__badge {
     /* remove border radius to allow icon to fill space */
     border-radius: 0;

     /* use a clip-path to form a quirky triangle */
     clip-path: polygon(100% 51%, 0 0, 3% 100%);

     height: 30px;
     width: 30px;
   }

   .my-badge {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     padding-right: 0.9em;
     font-size: 14px;
     height: 100%;
     color: #fff;
     background: green;
   }
   ```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RwpzaGZ)